# Binding UICollectionView with rest api data issue

Tags: ios, api, rest, uicollectionview

I am trying to grab images from external API and bind it to my UICollectionView & UIImageView cell with in that View. I am able to get the data and print it in the log file. However, I am not able to see the images on my UICollectionView. Here is the code to my data bindings.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ImagesViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  // imagesArray is an array with serialized json data.

  NSDictionary *finalImages = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSLog(@"Entering collection view.....");

  [[cell imageViewCell]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[finalImages valueForKey:@"link"]]];

  return cell;
}
```

The is data is coming in JSON format.

```
 data
{
  abc: 'abc',
  xyz: 'xyx',
  link: 'link to an online image'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imageNamed is a method to get image from a image file in your bundle (image.png).

In the case you want to get image from URL, download it as Mr Richhard Brown answer or use SDWebImage(set directly with imageView)

Sample colectionView SDWebImage code(nonARC): https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/CollectionViewNonARC.zip

Comment: - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is not firing for some reason. I tried having logs in this event and it doesn't print in my console.

Comment: Sure you setDatasource for collectionView or drag datasource to viewController?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply, but aaa & the example provided is very useful to figure out what went wrong. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage imageNamed:` takes a filename, not a URL.

You need to manually load the image file into an `NSData` object before you can display it.

`NSData dataWithContentsOfURL` will do this for you.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[finalImages valueForKey:@"link"]]];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. That makes so much sense. However, I am trying to print a log message and see the data in the log file. It doesn't print anything in the console. Looks like it's not firing the event in the first place. I am from .net background, so forgive my terminology.